# Observer pattern and data synchronization in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronization

I want to implement the observer pattern in Android. The observable and observers have to work in their own threads (`HandlerThread`). The observable object produces some results and notifies their observers **every milliseconds**. The observers register by passing themselves and `Handler` reference as arguments.

Example code:

```
public class Observable {

    public interface Observer {
        void notify(List<Object> results);
    }

    private HandlerThread handlerThread;
    private List<Object> results = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Map<Observer, ObserverWrapper> observers = new HashMap<>();

    private void working() {
        //Critial section...

        //modifying results list...

        synchronized (observers) {
            for (ObserverWrapper wrapper : observers.values()) {
                wrapper.notify(results);
            }
        }
    }

    public void register(Observer observer, Handler handler) {
        synchronized (observers) {
            //Create observer wrapper and add to map here...
        }
    }

    public void unregister(Observer observer) {
        synchronized (observers) {
            //Remove observer from the map...
        }
    }

    private static final class ObserverWrapper {
       private final Observer observer;
       private final Handler handler;

       public ObserverWrapper(Observer observer, Handler handler) {
           this.observer = observer;
           this.handler = handler;
       }

       public void notify(final List<Object> results) {
           //The observable thread

           handler.post(new Runnable() {
               void run() {
                   //The observer thread
                   //Critical section...
                   observer.notify(results);
               }
           });
       }
    }
}
```

The question is: **how to synchronize results list that is passed to all observers?** I cannot use a copy for each observer because it would cause high memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options I can think of:

1. Use the results object as a monitor. That requires minimum changes but this a) not very clean as object itself doesn't say anything about being a monitor. b) Given that the updates are coming every few milliseconds, there is a concern that observer threads will be locking the producer thread for extended periods of time. Both producer and the observer will have to:

   synchronized(results) {

   // ...

   }
2. Pass an explicit lock object to notify() and use it explicitely:

private final Object lock = new Object();

synchronized(lock) {
   // Update results
}

...
synchronized(lock) {
   // Read results
}

3. You mentioned that you don't want to copy results to reduce GC footprint, but this can be the most concurrent option. I'd do it if I were writing it. There is actually a better option, more optimistic option in terms of memory, which is CopyOnWriteArrayList, it will only copy if there is a simultaneous read and write:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Comment: I have just read that creating short lived objects is extremely cheap in JVM. My result object consists only of two double values. So maybe better option is creating mulitple objects rather than think about complicated synchronization with overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussions, here is the most concurrent way to do it:

```
private void working() {
        //Critial section...

        //modifying results list...

        // Create a copy for observers to process
        List resultsToProcess = new ArrayList(results);

        synchronized (observers) {
            for (ObserverWrapper wrapper : observers.values()) {
                wrapper.notify(resultsToProcess);
            }
        }
    }
```